# Get the index of a RadioGroup in Android

Tags: java, android, radio-group

I have two RadioButton in a RadioGroup:

```
<RadioGroup
    android:id="@+id/rgTripType"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="4" >

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/rbOneWay"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:checked="true"
        android:text="One Way" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/rbRound"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Round" />
</RadioGroup>
```

I am calling the RadioGroup in my Java file as:

```
    final RadioGroup rgTypeOfTrip = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.rgTripType);

        btnCalc.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                  Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, CALL FUNCTION GETINDEX() to get value, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        });

        rgTypeOfTrip.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                // Method 1
                int pos=rgTypeOfTrip.indexOfChild(findViewById(checkedId));
                    getIndex(pos);
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, String.valueOf(pos), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

public int getIndex(int k) {
    return k;
}
```

What it is supposed to do is display a Toast with the index of the radio button within the radio group. Instead, it causes my program to crash. Any idea how to resolve it?

**UPDATE**: The index issue is solved.

**Issue**: How can I use the index value (`POS`) in the `btnClick` function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It crashes because pos is an integer change. If you pass an int value as second paramter you are asking android to look for a String with id the int you provide. If it does not exists the  `ResourcesNotFoundException` will be thrown

```
Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, pos, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

with

```
 Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, String.valueOf(pos), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Comment: Wow that fixed it. Thanks! Only if compiler gave more informative message than just crash!

Comment: How would I use the ID in another function? Because it's a `void` function it can't return anything.

Comment: you can store it inside the SharedPreferences, for instance

Comment: I can not see any difference

Comment: are those snippet in the same file?

Comment: Yes, I am just trying to display different message based on the selection of the radio button in the radio group.

Comment: you can, for instance, assign pos to POS (`this.POS = pos` ) . is the value of pos 0 o 1?

Comment: Where would I add `this.POS=pos`?

Comment: inside setOnCheckedChangeListener, after ` int pos=rgTypeOfTrip.indexOfChild(findViewById(checkedId));` ?

Comment: I initialized POS: `final int POS;` inside onCreate function and added `this.POS = pos;` inside the `setOnCheckedChangeListener` function. I get the following error for the this.POS line, `POS cannot be resolved or is not a field`

Comment: declare POS as class memember and remove the final keyword

Comment: Can you please check my code again, I want to get the value in the getIndex() function inside the onClick() event?

Comment: why are you calling getIndex inside `rgTypeOfTrip.setOnCheckedChangeListener` ?

Comment: Because it's a void function it cannot return a value, so I am passing the pos value to an INT function which can return the value and it can b used inside the onClick method?

Comment: Or how would I go on about doing the class member as you suggested?

Comment: you have to understand the difference between getter and setter in java. In this case you can use a private class memeber

Answer (score 2):

There are different way ..
 I used this  way

```
        RadioGroup radiogroup = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.groupid);
    Button bt = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnDisplay);

    bt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // get selected radio button from radioGroup
            int selectedId = radiogroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
            switch (selectedId) {

                case R.id.radio_button1:
                 // do something..
                    break;
                case R.id.radio_button2:
                  // do something..
                    break;

            }


        }
    });
```

Comment: This is the answer i was looking for. Thanks!